# Can you bind separate date and time fields to a single DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Our interface has the date and time in separate boxes. One box for date (with a `DatePicker`), one box for time (as a `TextBox`).

Is it possible to databind a single `DateTime` (or preferably a nullable `DateTime`) to these separate values? (If not, what alternatives are there?)

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you setup your datasource so that it has a date column and a time column?

Comment: No, the data source is a date and time SQL column that we can not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your interface create a public property or method for retrieving the entire date.  This method or property will then create the date using your interface fields.  What you have done sounds like a user friendly interface as clear separation of the two is logical.

```
public DateTime GetDateTime(){
    return new DateTime(DateControl.Year,DateControl.Month,DateControl.Day,TimeControl.Hour,TimeControl.Minute);
}
```

As an example this could be a possible method on your interface which can be consumed!

Subquently you could have a set method which takes a datetime and you then split of the values and bind the two controls. :-)

Andrew

Comment: This sounds like a 'no' on the can you bind two controls directly to the date time. The problem is, we would like to bind directly to a dumb message, that does not have anything other than the fields, which in this case is a date time. If not, we'll have to find a work around, but the preference is to do it directly.

Comment: As long as your date field HAS a time, then passing that date to a Time Control should just extract the time value and a Date Control the date value.  It depends on how the control was built.  Is it a .NET user control?  Does it have a DataSource property?  If it doesn't you could create a wrapper around the control and add the DataBinding yourself.

Comment: At this point it is not a control of any kind, it is two separate controls. I see what you mean about the wrapper though. Thanks much for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible!

### Scenario

1. Have two distinct `DateTimePicker` fields in the UI, one representing date and another representing time. Example:

```
DateTimePicker dtpDate;
DateTimePicker dtpTime;
```

2. Have a model with a single `DateTime` property. Example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public DateTime? When;
}
```

### What we're trying to do?

Change the model's `When` property automatically when there's a change in any of the mentioned UI controls, and vice-versa;

### Solution

Make your **model class bindable** and **have 2 extra properties that act like a bridge (proxy) between the `When` property and the fields that represent a partial `DateTime` value** (e.g.: one `DateTimePicker` for date, and another for time). These proxies are needed because when there's a change in any of the UI controls, we need to know which components/parts of the `DateTime` will need to be changed. Is it the date or the time?

Now, the following code does quite a bit. First, you want to react to any changes to any of the proxies (`ProxyWhenDate` and `ProxyWhenTime`), reflecting this change into the resulting `DateTime` (`When`), and vice-versa. To make this work, you need to make this class bindable. You do that by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and implementing custom property setters that raise a `PropertyChanged` event with the corresponding property name.

Example:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Bindable properties

    private DateTime? _When;
    public virtual DateTime? When
    {
        get { return _When; }
        set
        {
            SetField(ref _When, value);
            // When a change to `When` occurs, it means `ProxyWhenDate` and `ProxyWhenTime` have been changed as well,
            // so we need to raise a `PropertyChanged` notification for both of them.
            NotifyPropertyChanged(this.GetPropertyName((MyModel x) => x.ProxyWhenDate));
            NotifyPropertyChanged(this.GetPropertyName((MyModel x) => x.ProxyWhenTime));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Proxies

    public virtual DateTime ProxyWhenDate
    {
        get
        {
            return When.HasValue ? When.Value : DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        set
        {
            DateTime v = When.HasValue ? When.Value : DateTime.UtcNow;
            // Change only Year + Month + Day, keeping the rest as it is.
            When = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, v.Hour, v.Minute, v.Second);
        }
    }

    public virtual DateTime ProxyWhenTime
    {
        get
        {
            return When.HasValue ? When.Value : DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        set
        {
            DateTime v = When.HasValue ? When.Value : DateTime.UtcNow;
            // Change only Hour + Minute + Second, keeping the rest as it is.
            When = new DateTime(v.Year, v.Month, v.Day, value.Hour, value.Minute, value.Second);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Object extensions

    public static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TField>(this Object obj, Expression<Func<TSource, TField>> Field)
    {
        return (Field.Body as MemberExpression ?? ((UnaryExpression)Field.Body).Operand as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Support for bindings

    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // NotifyPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event passing the
    // source property that is being updated.
    public virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property)
    {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)property;
        MemberExpression memberExpression;
        if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
        }
        else
        {
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged(memberExpression.Member.Name);
    }

    public virtual bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now all you have to do is to create bindings between UI controls' properties and your model properties. Example:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private MyModel Model;

    public MyForm(MyModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Model = model;

        // Create our bindings

        dtpDate.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", Model,
            this.GetPropertyName((MyModel x) => x.ProxyWhenDate)));

        dtpTime.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", Model,
            this.GetPropertyName((MyModel x) => x.ProxyWhenTime)));
    }
}
```

Done! Enjoy the magic, and sorry for being ~6 years late ;-)

NOTE: The attribute [`CallerMemberName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was introduced in .NET Framework 4.5, but you can live without it by changing only a few lines of code.